# How do I code a USB-TCP relay?

Tags: python, tcp, usb

I would like to be able to read and write with a USB port from a remote machine as if it were local. I want to do this by writing a python script that establishes a TCP connection to the remote machine and then constantly reads from the USB port and write to the TCP connection and vice versa. What is the best way to code this up in Python simply and quickly?

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/

Comment: Start by reading the top results for the relevant google searches

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the same thing you're asking for a robotics project I had in the past year. We had a Raspberry Pi constantly reading on a USB port linked to an Arduino board, and as soon as it got some message it sent it throught TCP to all the remote clients connected.

The project is called `autonomee` and [is available on github](https://github.com/halflings/autonomee).

To summarize, you have to do the following:

1. The 'client' connects to the server that is linked to the USB "source"
2. Have a thread (on the server) constantly reading from the USB (I'd recommend using [`pyserial`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) or [`pyusb`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/) for that)
3. When you receive some data, send it throught TCP to the remote client (more on that below)
4. The remote client keeps listening for data and whenever it gets a message it processes it

The most thought part is the TCP connection, and it's not *that* hard.

You can either use [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) for a higher level TCP server or just use the standard [`TCPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) class (we did the latter). Check the examples on the `SocketServer` doc, they are really useful !

I can't give you much more detail as it highly depends on which kind of data you have to send, at which frequency, but I'd advise you to have a look at the code I've produced for the [server](https://github.com/halflings/autonomee/blob/master/server.py) and the [client](https://github.com/halflings/autonomee/blob/master/carsocket.py)

Comment: Notice that I'm not really proud of the way I built my client, so uh, probably not the best source of inspiration :-)